# Arrow keys not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, keypress

We're creating a slideshow in HTML/CSS/JS but it isn't working in Firefox for some reason. It works in Webkit browsers without a problem..

The code is this:

```
    keyPress : function() {
      $( document.body ).keydown(function(e) {
         if ( e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39 || e.which == 37 || e.which === 39) {
            e.preventDefault();
            ( e.keyCode === 39 || e.which === 39 ) ? Slides.next() : Slides.prev();
         }
      });
   },
```

If I use just `$( document )` instead of `( document.body )` it does change my colours, but the slides don't change..

For some reason, Firefox (7.0.1, OSX Lion) doesn't pick up the keypresses.. It works in Safari/Chrome without a problem.

The site we're testing this on is : #took link out

Comment: May I respectfully suggest that you provide a way to click through the slides, as well as arrow-keying through them?

Comment: Yes, it's on the todo list; but I want it to work in Firefox :(

Comment: Use Firebug to inspect the `e` object to find out what methods and properties it supports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I think your problem lies in the use of the "document.body" selector. This works for me in Chrome but not in Firefox ( http://jsfiddle.net/Jncrh/2/ ) Try just selecting "document" instead and see if it behaves. ( http://jsfiddle.net/Jncrh/5/ )

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
    if (e.which==37 || e.which==39) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.which==37) {
            alert("going back");
        } else {
            alert("going forward");
        }
    }
});
```

Firefox *can* pick up the keypresses in the above sample, so I suspect the problem lies elsewhere in your code.

**PREVIOUS:** A quick Google search reveals that Firefox uses `event.charCode` instead of `event.keyCode`. Try this:

```
key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which ? e.which : e.charCode;
if (key===37 || key===39) {...
```

However, jQuery *should* be able to pick up all of those with its own [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/), so I don't understand why that isn't working as-is for you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me though.. :\
if ( e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39 || e.charCode === 37 || e.charCode === 39) {

Comment: I honestly don't understand why it doesn't work.. Like you said, I figured the 'which' would pick it up, but alas. Does it work for you in Firefox?

Comment: If I change it to (document) it changes my colours but not my slides.. They don't animate for some reason. I'll try working from $(document) and see if I can fix the problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ($.browser.mozilla) {     
        $(document).keypress (keyType); 
    } 
    else{
       $(document).keydown (keyType);
    }

    function keyType(e){
    if (e.keyCode==37 || e.keyCode==39) { 
        e.preventDefault();         
        if (e.which==37) {             
           //handle left
        } 
        else { 
          //handle right      
        }       
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `keydown` and `keyup` events, all major browsers support the `keyCode` property of the corresponding event, so there's no need for the `which` property. Also, to catch key events on the whole document, you need to attach the listener to the document rather than the body.

Here's the definitive page on JavaScript key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

And here's a revised version of your code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var leftArrow = (e.keyCode == 37), rightArrow = (e.keyCode == 39);
    if (leftArrow || rightArrow) {
        e.preventDefault();
        rightArrow ? Slides.next() : Slides.prev();
    }
});
```